# How to use PowerMockito to verify super method is called

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am testing a legacy code that use inheritance method. I am trying to mock super-method
to verity if the super-method is being call or not.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class HumanTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        // 1. arrange
        Human sut = PowerMockito.spy(new Human());
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when((SuperHuman) sut).run(); // SuperHuman is the parent class

        // 2. action
        sut.run();

        // 3. assert / verify
    }
}

public class Human extends SuperHuman {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("human run");

        super.run();
    }
}

public class SuperHuman {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("superhuman run");
    }
}
```

I was expecting that "human run" will be printed. But the actual result was none printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when((SuperHuman) sut).run(); // SuperHuman is the parent class
```

This won't work in your case since PowerMockito will mock method of Human even if you made cast.
I checked your code example and could say that it is possible to suppress invocation of super class method with:

```
Method toReplace = PowerMockito.method(SuperHuman.class, "run");
PowerMockito.suppress(toReplace);
```

But it seems that method replacment feature does not work for methods of super class:
[createPartialMock should support mocking overridden methods in super classes.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=51)

So this does not work:

```
    PowerMockito.replace(toReplace).with(new InvocationHandler() {
    
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Method of superclass has been invoked !");
        return null;
    }
    });
```

But still you should be able to verify invocation of super method let's say indirectly, by mocking other classes which are invoked in super method only.
For instance check that System.out.println was invoked with "superhuman run" or something like this.